# Custom iPhone Icon

Tags: iphone, icons

This is not a technical question, but given that there are a few iPhone developers on here I figured I'd ask.  Are there design firms advertising services for designing custom iPhone icons?

Comment: Why not make it through CoreGraphics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure that you can find plenty on the web, just google it.

[Icon Factory](http://iconfactory.com/design/) and [IconShock](http://www.iconshock.com/professional-icons.php) are one of my favorites, but there are individuals that can make you what you need for a price, **just ask them**, take a look for example at the icons made by **[Made By Sofa](http://www.madebysofa.com/#work)** company, I do love them, and I would suggest you to contact them directly, they made pretty famous icons on the market!

but for the iPhone, you will need a 75x75 pixels icon in PNG format, the round curves are made automatically by the iPhone OS.

you can test it using a webpage, just add this line of code in your HTML page (Head section):

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="myIcon.png" />
```

and bookmark it to the homepage with an iPhone or iPod Touch

Comment: Surely you mean 57x57 pixel icon instead of 75x75. Also, you will need a 512x512 pixel version when you submit your application to the App Store.

Comment: I really mean 75x75 pixels :) at least that's the webApps icon size

Comment: I'm sorry but you're mistaken. The application icon for a SDK application and the apple-touch-icon are 57x57 PNGs.
http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/iPhoneWebAppHIG/MetricsLayout/chapter_5_section_2.html

Answer (score 3):

Any graphic designer can make an iPhone icon. There's no specialised skill required.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google found [SoftFacade](http://www.softfacade.com/) and [FastIcon](http://fasticon.com).  Though, I don't think you'd need to look for only "iphone icon" artists.  If you can find and icon you like, it's pretty easy to give it the [iphone](http://tutorials20.com/design/design-your-iphone-widgets/) [look](http://www.photoshopvids.com/photshop-tutorials/photoshop-tutorial-how-to-make-iphone-icons/).